# How to pause javascript after executing a script for some time and then resume?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make js gallery with image change, when user rollovers the thumbnail.
I have made it successfully and used css3 fade-in animation for image change, it works ok, but if I rollover my cursor on thumb1, dont wait for the animation to finish and rollover on another thumbnail the image changes without animation. It is hard to explain because my English is not the best, so i'll give you my code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="#css21" media="screen"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html id="xhtml10S" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta http-equiv="Window-target" content="_top" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>Untitled-1</title>
<style id="css21" type="text/css" media="screen">
html, body {
color : #405060;
font : normal normal normal 95%/1.5 Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, san-serif;
height : auto;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
text-align : center;
width : auto; }
body {
background-color : #000000; }
div {
border : none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0; }
div#gscreen {
float : none;
height : 250px;
width : 100%;
clear : both;

-webkit-transition: background 1500ms ease-in 0ms; /* property duration timing-function delay */
-moz-transition: background 1500ms ease-in 0ms;
-o-transition: background 1500ms ease-in 0ms;
transition: background 1500ms ease-in 0ms;  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


var imageGallery = ( function() {

var xelem = ( function( xTag ) {
var ua = ((( ie = document.all.tags( xTag )) && !!!( ff = document.getElementsByTagName( xTag ))) ? 1 : 0 );
var xObj = null || { 0 : ff, 1 : ie }[ ua ];
return xObj;
} );
return function imageGallery( tagX ) {
var xItem = xelem("div");
var xScreen = xItem["gscreen"];
var xImg = xelem( tagX );
var iLen = xImg.length;
for ( i = 0; !!( xImg[ i ] ); i++ ) {
xImg[ i ].onmouseover = function() {
var xIndex = Number( this.id.match(/\d+/)[ 0 ] );
xScreen.style.background = " url(" + this.src + ") no-repeat top center";

}
}
}
} )();
onload = function() {
imageGallery("img")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gscreen"></div>

<img id="i0" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMMlTzBMWSeD6IrQCLTT7urbpXORjY_2vqmA_mFj6OJcsfsH-yuw" height="100" width="200" style="background-image='url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMMlTzBMWSeD6IrQCLTT7urbpXORjY_2vqmA_mFj6OJcsfsH-yuw)'" alt="test images" />
<img id="i1" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSlGvpoCsCgGcX74IWG5YNmjULh1Q428frxtmabTCNM_aVKFGH9" style="background-image='url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMMlTzBMWSeD6IrQCLTT7urbpXORjY_2vqmA_mFj6OJcsfsH-yuw)'" height="100" width="200" alt="test images" />
<img id="i2" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3DluQXJW-4stVrHlArRc6gZnuxqmKKyheZsDWt-kGjvfjj43M" height="100" width="200" style="background-image='url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMMlTzBMWSeD6IrQCLTT7urbpXORjY_2vqmA_mFj6OJcsfsH-yuw)'" alt="test images" />
<img id="i3" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDC56QxLfOgZyrX96BfPveif-dKlrDIwsB45uGlL3XicDL10EqlA" height="100" width="200" style="background-image='url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMMlTzBMWSeD6IrQCLTT7urbpXORjY_2vqmA_mFj6OJcsfsH-yuw)'" alt="test images" />

</body>
</html>
```

So, I think if I pause javascript for 1500ms after executing "onmouseover" user will not be able to execute the function again when rollovering another thumbnail, how can I do that? Or maybe there are more options to fix the image change effect?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can try with jquery function setTimeOut();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Example:

```
// run this code after 1500ms
setTimeout(function () {
   // this code will run later;
   alert("Hello World");
},1500);
```

**UPDATE:** In your case

```
xImg[ i ].onmouseover = function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var xIndex = Number( that.id.match(/\d+/)[ 0 ] );
        xScreen.style.background = " url(" + that.src + ") no-repeat top center";
    },1500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering :) But Can you give me an example in my code because I don't know how to use it. I dont want that any function would be executed after 1500ms timeout unless user rollovers the thumbnail. thank you :)

Comment: Well, it works with with 2 thumbnails but if I wipe my cursor through 3 thumbs or more it suddenly changes the image and does not wait for previous animation to finish. :/

Comment: well you will have to implement that logic your self, i am just showing you how to make the code run on a timer

Answer (score 0):

I would give `imageGallery` a property like `imageGallery.isReady = true;` When the function starts, set the property to `false`. Then, at the end of your function, do `setTimeout(function() {imageGallery.isReady = true;}, 1500);`

When the function is called, just check if `imageGallery.isReady = true;` If it's not, don't execute the function; if it is, execute it.

Edit: Alternatively, you could remove the event listener when the function starts, and then add it again after a `setTimeout();`

Comment: Thank you for answering, i don't know how to use "setTimeout" function in my code because as I don't want that any function would be executed after 1500ms timeout if user does not roll over the thumbnail. And it would be cool if you show me an example with true/false because I have never used something like this :D Thanks again :)